# how to run for loop inside an it spec of jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

1/ below is my spec

```
function testRunner(count) {
      it('test', async function () {
            console.log(count+"FIRST")
            for(var j=0;j<count.length;j++)
            { 
                console.log(count+"SECOND")
                specExecutor.execute(test)
            }       
      });
    } 


  count = 1
  for (var i=1; i<5; i++) {
        count = count+1;
        testRunner(count); //run testrunner 2 times; count = 2
    }
```

When I run above code, for loop inside spec doesn't execute at all and hence `specExecutor.exeute` don't trigger.

How to handle such use-case?

My requirement is to execute multiple tests inside one spec based on count so that all results will be under the required spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not count.length in your loop inside the testRunner function. It is just count

```
for(var j=0;j<count;j++) { 
  console.log(count+"SECOND")
  specExecutor.execute(test)
}
```